# OSGi enroute and Apache CXF

Tags: osgi, cxf

I have successfully deployed SOAP services via Apache CXF within Apache Karaf, but would now like to do the same with OSGi enroute.  I suspect my sticking point is the jaxws:endpoint definition, still pursuing resolution.

With that said, does anyone know of a working example of Apache CXF within OSGi enroute that I could reference?

Comment: OSGi enRoute is 100% OSGi so if it runs on Karaf it should also run on OSGi enRoute. You have to add the CXF bundles of course. I would love to have an example of such a project on the OSGi enRoute website and I could give you a hand. We already have a number of these projects.

Comment: On Karaf... I configured my jaxws:endpoint within a blueprint file.  Not sure where CXF could find this endpoint without the blueprint file.  I'm sure I'll figure this out at some point and will contribute working example when finished.  Some pointers would certainly be helpful.